# syntax error: arguments for super() in pygame

Tags: python, python-2.7, pygame

I'm currently using Pycharm newest updated version.The interpreter I use is Python 2.7 in pycharm, therefore I can install Pygame, but I cannot install Pygame package.

This is the error:

```
Python version 2.7 does not support this syntax. super() should have arguments in Python 2:10
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: [Discourage screenshots of code and/or errors](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/303812/discourage-screenshots-of-code-and-or-errors)

Comment: Please read up on the super() usage: https://www.pythonforbeginners.com/super/working-python-super-function/

Comment: FWIW, you can use [Python 2 syntax](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#super) (which required arguments) just fine in Python 3 which does not require them — however the inverse is not true.

Comment: thank you, will look forward to copy/paste the code in the future instead of posting images.

Comment: "The interpreter I use is Python 2.7 in pycharm, therefore I can install Pygame, otherwise, I cannot install Pygame package." Of course you can. Indeed, the [Pygame website itselfs suggest you use 3.7.7 or greater](https://www.pygame.org/wiki/GettingStarted). Don't use Python 2, it is beyond it's end of life and no longer supported.

Comment: Thank you, d @martineau, I used the python 2 way of using super(), as super(subclass, self).__init__,

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga, for real? I really do think that the pygame does not support over python 3.7 or above? because last time i was using python 3.8, and I can't not install pip and pygame properly in my Pycharm.

Comment: That sounds like some other issue. Note, you shouldn't have to install pip, it is generally distributed with Python

Comment: You are quite wrong about `pygame` not supporting versions of Python beyond 3.7. I use PyCharm for development with `pygame` and Python 3.9. I believe you must have misinterpreted whatever problem you had installing `pygame`. You can't install `pip` on Python 3 because it comes as part of the standard install.

Answer (score 0):

The syntax in Python 2 is different. See [`super()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#super). The *type* argument is not optional. The typical superclass call looks like this:

<s>`super().__init__()`</s>

```py
super(Bullet, self).__init__()
```

This syntax is also valid in Python 3.